# H2 Database: now() as nano seconds

Tags: sql, h2

I would like to diff a date stored as nanoseconds in a column with current time, to only fetch records that are less than 60 minutes old.

Any ideas how to do this?

Perhaps its possible use the now() function some how.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the datatype of that column?

Comment: It's the datatype LONG.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [timestampadd](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) something like this:-

```
where x > timestampadd(minute, -60, now());
```

(This is a copy of the answer from [LearnedfromMistake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501794/learnedfrommistake) who unfortunately deleted his answer because he thought it only works with MySQL and not H2).

To convert a timestamp to millis, you could use

```
datediff('ms', '1970-01-01', now())
```

Please be aware that `System.currentTimeMillis()` will give you the milliseconds since 1970 UTC, which is most likely not the local timezone, so you could get into trouble with that.

Comment: No, `x` would need to be a timestamp. But I guess the person who asked the question already knowns how he wants to convert a timestamp to a `LONG`, as this is what he did already (for whatever reason).

Comment: Actually, I would like to know how to convert a timestamp to LONG. The suggested solution gives an error:
Data conversion error converting "2013-03-17 20:26:21.551"; SQL statement:
SELECT count(*) FROM MESSAGES where INSERT_NANOTIME  > timestampadd(minute, -60, now()) [22018-164] 22018/22018

Comment: @user955732, how did you originally insert the value into `x`? If you have done the conversation to milliseconds within a Java program, then you should probably also do the conversion for the value to compare to in the Java program.

Comment: I am using java's System.nanoTime()

Comment: @user955732 System.nanoTime() is the nanoseconds since the process was started. The value is reset whenever you restart the application. I don't think this is what you actually want, right?

Comment: oops, I didn't know that. I will have to change it to milliseconds then. But how to get rid of the data conversion error when comparing timeestamp in h2 with a column with datatype LONG, actually stored value from java's currentTimeMillis() ?

Comment: To convert a timestamp to millis, you could use `datediff('ms', '1970-01-01', now())`. Please be aware that `System.currentTimeMillis()` will give you the milliseconds since 1970 UTC, which is most likely not the local timezone, so you could get into trouble with that.